# Single buck converter for multiple fans with different speeds?

Tags: voltage, buck

I need to switch a 3d printer motherboard which controls some fans, the new one outputs 24V instead of 5V, but each fan is 5V. Each fan will need to be spun up/down independently from the other two. I have enough DC buck converters (LM2596), and I'm fairly sure I can use them to drop from 24V down to 5V without issues. Is there a way to only use a single buck converter, and send 5V to all fans while keeping the ability to spin them up/down independently? It's not something that I *need*, but since I am a newbie in this field I would like to learn more about it

Thank you!

Edit: both motherboards have separate outputs for controlling each fan

Comment: What are the fans? How are they controlled? What speed outputs do you have? What is controlling the speed of the fans?

Comment: @Puffafish Rewording my deleted comment: the fans are 5V DC 2pin fans. The motherboard has corresponding 2 pin headers. The fans right now are only used at 0% or 100%, not in-betweens if it can help (but may be useful to have full speed control).

Comment: What comes out of these 2 pin headers? Are these 5V or 24V?

Comment: the old motherboard outputs 5V, the new one 24V

Comment: The easy solution would be to replace the fans with 24V versions.

Comment: @rdtsc I know and they are being shipped, but it's not a solution to my question

Comment: We need to know the layout and schematic of the motherboard to answer your question. It is possible to do what you want, but how to do it depends on the routing and set up of the motherboard.

Comment: @Puffafish damn I didn't think it would have been such an involved question. Here are all the resources that are available to the public https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V3.0/Hardware. I also added an edit to my question to be more clear regarding my setup

Comment: By "spun up/down independently" do you need independent speed control or just independent on/off control?

Comment: @user253751 I would like independent speed control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fans have only two pins, the only way to control them is to vary their supply voltage, for example by PWM or by changing the supply voltage directly.

There is no way to control them individually. That would require either a separate DCDC converter for each of them or fans that have an integrated speed controller, like 4-pin PC fans do.

How such a solution would be compatible with your given hardware and software is a different story.

Comment: edited my question, I have enough ports for each fan, but I would have to add a buck converter to each output in order to use each fan. I want to know if there's a way to only use one to drop the voltage for all the fans

Comment: @HitLuca You asked if it was possible to control then "independently" and that's not possible with one buck converter.

Comment: @HitLuca what do the ports on the new MB output? PWM'ed 24V on two pins?

Comment: yes, 24V on two pins, here are the details https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V3.0/Hardware

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer on a similar reddit question: "Do read up how to use a buck converter to power a PWM fan. You don't connect the input of the buck converter to the original PWM fan port, but to the 24V power rail. You don't connect the 12V fan negative to the buck converter output either, but to the negative connection on the original fan port, since that's what carries the PWM signal. All the buck converter does is provide stable 12V, so it can do that for several fans at once." https://www.reddit.com/r/BIGTREETECH/comments/se1i1z/skr_mini_e3_v30_pwm_controlled_fans/